# Unregister COM component in WIX during rollback, is it necessary?

Tags: installation, wix, com-interop, rollback

I am creating a WIX installer project. Part of the work in the installation is to register some COM component. I have (hopefully) succeeded with that by using heat.exe to generate the COM component declaration, although I needed to modify a little after the wxs files were generated. To make it clear, I am pasting my COM component declaration here:

```
<ComponentGroup Id="COMComponent" Directory="INSTALLDIR">        
      <Component Id="COMDll" Guid="MY_GUID1">
        <Class Id="{MY_CLASSID1}" Context="InprocServer32" Description="DESCRIPTION1" ThreadingModel="both" ForeignServer="mscoree.dll">
          <ProgId Id="MYID1" Description="DESCRIPTION1" />
        </Class>
...
        <File Id="FILE_ID_1" KeyPath="yes" Source="MY_COM.dll" />  

        <File Id="FILD_ID2" KeyPath="no" Source="MY_COM.tlb">
          <TypeLib Id="{xxx}" Description="xxx" HelpDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Language="0" MajorVersion="525" MinorVersion="0">
            <Interface Id="{xxx}" Name="xxx" ProxyStubClassId32="{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}" />
...
          </TypeLib>
        </File>

        <ProgId Id="Record" />
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{xxx}\Implemented Categories\{xxx}"  Value="" Type="string" Action="write" />
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{xxx}\InprocServer32\525.0.4573.25681" Name="Class" Value=" MYID1" Type="string" Action="write" />
...
        </Component>                          
    </ComponentGroup>
```

I replaced some IDs with xxx, so they are not a problem. If there is anything else wrong, please inform me.

Now my question is: do I need to explicitly specify to uninstall the COM component in the rollback phase? Because I have experienced some problem, that after some failure installation, the further tries of installations wouldn't go through and some "ActiveX object can't be created" error popped up. I suspected it is because COM component was not unregistered successfully in the previous fail installation. But I am not sure. In fact I have limited knowledge in COM interop, so I am not sure what's necessary for install/uninstall them. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use Heat to harvest the COM components, that will be sufficient. It should handle unregistering your COM components if the installation fails and is rolled back.